# Server socket - accept connections only from IP addresses in the whitelist

Tags: c++, sockets, serversocket, ip-restrictions

I have a socket server that listens and accepts connections from client, which works as follow:

```
... do some pre-processing (socket, binds, etc)
//listen to client
if (listen(sockfd, BACKLOG) == -1) {
        perror("listen");
        exit(1);
}

printf("server: waiting for connections...\n");

while(1) {  // main accept() loop
    sin_size = sizeof client_addr;
    new_fd = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&their_addr, &sin_size);
    if (new_fd == -1) {
        perror("accept");
        continue;
    }
     //do something .....
    .....
}
```

How can I restrict the server so it only accepts connection from specific IP addresses? For instance, I can create a text file containing a white list of IP addresses to accept, in the following format:
202.168.2.5 - 202.168.2.127
92.104.3.1 - 92.104.4.254
//and so on

So basically I want to reject connection from all the IP addresses not included in the whitelist. If the socket library API does not support this, I am okay with the idea of accepting the connections first, then just immediately close the socketfd if the peeraddress is not in the whitelist. But how to perform this, how can I check that a specific IP address is within the range specified in my whitelist? Any examples would be appreciated.

Comment: You don't mention an OS, but if you're running on a *nix system you can simply use TCP Wrappers and let it do the work for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<s>You want to call **[getpeername](http://www.beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/multipage/getpeernameman.html)** to get the address information from the client.</s> Then check if their IP address is found in the whitelist. If not, disconnect them.

In order to check that their ip address lies within a given range, you want to convert the address bytes into one number. You can do that with the following:

```
unsigned int n = bytes[0] << 24 | bytes[1] << 16 | bytes[2] << 8 | bytes[3];
```

If the lower bound of the address range is A, and the upper bound is B, and the client's ip address is X, then they are white listed `if (A <= X && X <= B)`.

If each range of ip addresses tests false, then they aren't on the white list and you should disconnect them.

Comment: Ahh, okay, make sense. I was doing a lot of if-else to check whether or not it is within the allowed IP range. Doing a bit shifting is a perfect solution. Thanks !!

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what the question is here, or rather what the problem is. The client's address will be in `their_addr`, so just search your whitelist for that. If not found, close. You will probably want to either convert `their_addr` into the same format as your whitelist entries, or possibly vice versa.

Comment: I mentioned this in the last paragraph of my question. My next question is then: how can I check that a particular IP address is within a specific range? For instance, 92.104.3.120 is within the range of 92.104.3.1 and 92.104.4.254.

Comment: @all_by_grace If the ranges are all subnets you can just mask. Otherwise you will need to organize a suitable data structure. It's a data structure question, not a networking question.

Comment: @all_by_grace - convert start and end IP address to a network byte order `int` using `inet_pton`; you now have a range to check against.

Comment: @BrianRoach: Yes, thanks ! Problem solved! Either using inet_pton(), or using the bit shifting as specified in Marlon's answer, would solve this.

Answer (score 1):

On Windows only, you can use `WSAAccept()` instead of `accept()`.  `WSAAccept()` has a parameter that you can pass a callback function to.  Before a new connection is accepted, the callback is invoked with the addresses and QOS values for that connection.  The callback can then return `CF_ACCEPT`, `CF_DEFER`, or `CF_REJECT` as needed.